# Linq to SQL and randomly resetting data base table

Tags: linq-to-sql

We have an issue we are seeing where a table seems to be getting reset, the records are deleted and the primary key is reset. This then causes issues with another table that joins to it. I have a theory it might be to do with the connection dropping out when trying to retrieve info from the data context and then submitting a blank/default table. It looks like the data context is being reused rather than creating a new one for each unit of work which I think is the wrong thing to do but i was wondering if this would be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Are you calling `DataContext.CreateDatabase`? Otherwise I see no reason for this.

Comment: We're going to need more to go on, like some source code for starters. Is there any place in your code where the table gets TRUNCATEd or the records get DELETEd? Consider setting a breakpoint there and noting how it's getting called.

Comment: Not that i can see. deleting the data is not needed so it was never implemented

Answer (score -1):

when i used local database, i faced same problem. in every run,
visual studio adds main database files into the debug folder and overwrites. 
so i see blank database after run. but there is no problem,
because after releasing the solution it happenings not same, and problem disappears.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add more details to your solution. As it is, its not very clear how you solved the issue.

Comment: thank you. open server explorer tab, right click on db file, modify connection. add "\bin\Debug" before "db.mdf". then you can see the datas in table just for one run. next run system copies the first creadet db.mdf and its log file into the \bin\Debug file. that means it resets the db. actually this is enoug and good thing for me.

Comment: Yes, but in that case the "other table" would be gone as well. This doesn't answer this old question that's probably not relevant anymore.

Comment: when the program run, it uses the new created database and next run the changes on last session are already gone. but changes made on tables, views etc. in visual studio are not disappear. because runtime uses new created (in \bin folder] database and visual studio uses root database (first location). just new entries during runtime disappear. thats all.